# Error handling in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, exception, try-catch

Below is some code I wrote:

```
func Begin(input: String) -> Double {
     let inputs = (input as NSString).lowercaseString
     var smth = AnalyzeInput(input: inputs)
     return smth.findOutput()
}
```

Line 3 of this code (the 'smth' declaration) begins a long series of code that, at many instances, may throw some kind of an error (typically an index out of bounds error when creating a substring). Because this code is about 5,000 lines in 15 different files, and manually handling each exception would take a long time for each one, I would greatly prefer to not have to manually handle these exceptions.

I understand that there is no try / catch / finally structure in Swift, but is there anything where I can mimic that functionality? Or did I just dig myself into a giant hole?

Answer (score 1):

If you're throwing exceptions in cases that are not catastrophic errors (i.e. you expect to crash soon), then you've dug yourself a hole. Cocoa does not use exceptions for general error handling. It uses them for truly exceptional situations. It's up to you to avoid index-out-of-bounds.

See the [Error Handling Programming Guide for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html) for documentation on Cocoa error handling. Your function should likely look something like this:

```
func begin(input: String, error: NSErrorPtr) -> Double? {
     let inputs = input.lowercaseString // "as NSString" is no longer needed
     let smth = AnalyzeInput(input: inputs, error: NSErrorPtr) // pass along your error pointer
     return smth?.findOutput() // Use ?. to return nil if smth is nil, or Double? otherwise
}
```

Some of us are exploring more functional approaches, such as a [Result](https://github.com/LlamaKit/LlamaKit/blob/parameterize/LlamaKit/Result.swift) object. These are all still pretty experimental, but in principle it would look like this:

```
func begin(input: String) -> Result<Double, NSError> {
     let inputs = input.lowercaseString
     let smth = AnalyzeInput(input: inputs) // AnalyzeInput would return a Result
     return smth.map { $0.findOutput() } // And then we map it to the final result
}
```